# How to add two non strings together...?

Tags: python

I am using the colorama module and I want to be able to call the Fore on a variable corresponding to a color, for example 'GREEN'. I want to be able to do:

```
from colorama import Fore
color = 'GREEN'
print(Fore. + color)
```

I wanted it to just run print(Fore.GREEN), but I can't because its a syntax error. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are describing the basic usage of the built-in function [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
>>> getattr(Fore, "GREEN")
'\x1b[32m'
```

This is useful when you have the name of an attribute stored in a variable.